# Drupal 7 - Getting already loaded nodes

Tags: drupal-7

Is it possible to access already loaded nodes within a region template? This is to prevent re-querying the same thing twice. I know that I can load nodes with `nid` using `node_load`, which if the node is already loaded it will retrieve the node from static cache. But for this case I don't know the `nid` so I prefer getting a list of `nid`s already loaded.

PS: Using PDO results are cached so there won't be much performance drop even though I query the same thing several times but still I prefer minimizing database contact as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use hook_node_load() and append the loaded nid to an array (maybe global), to store the information about loaded nodes.

Later on use node_load_multiple( [array of loaded nids]) and you'll get all the nodes from cache!

Here it is:

```
/**
 * Nid array set function
 */
function mymodule_push_nid_array($nid) {
  global $nid_array;
  if (!isset($nid_array)) {
    $nid_array = array();
  }
  // Only push, if nid isn't already set
  if(!in_array($nid, $nid_array)) {
    array_push($nid_array, $nid);
  }
}

/**
 * Nid array get function
 */
function mymodule_get_nid_array() {
  global $nid_array;
  if(!isset($nid_array)) {
    return array();
  }
  else {
    return $nid_array;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_load();
 */
function mymodule_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    mymodule_push_nid_array($node->nid);
  }
}

/**
 * Returns already loaded nodes
 */
function mymodule_get_all_loaded_nodes() {
  return node_load_multiple(mymodule_get_nid_array());
}

/**
 * Demo function (shows only up on next page request!)
 * Don't use THIS HOOK IN PRODUCTION
 */
function mymodule_exit() {
  $nodes = mymodule_get_all_loaded_nodes();
  debug($nodes);
}
```

This is working code but quickly prototyped. Feel free to modify.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I've read the documentation but I did not understand how to use this function.

Comment: Okay, i wrote the code down. Hope you can handle it and do understand the hook and module system.